# Jquery get slider value while changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an issue with a slider that shall give me its constant value while its dragged.

My *html* code is as follows:

```
<div class="dimmer">
      <div class="intensity-slider">
        <!--<label for="fader">INTENSITY</label>-->
        <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="80" class="vertical" orient="vertical" id="fader" step="1" oninput="outputUpdate(value)">
        <output class="output" for="fader" id="intensity">80</output>
        <script>

          function outputUpdate(int) {
          document.querySelector('#intensity').value = int;
          }
        </script>
      </div>
      <div class="blackout">
        <a ontouchstart="" href="#" id="blackout">BO</a>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Now, I have the output class intensity, and its getting updated while I drag the slider.

I need to get this value now also to be updated for my jQuery `consolelog`.

Here is my *JavaScript* code:

```
$( "#fader" ).mousedown(function(value) {
    console.log(document.querySelector('#intensity').value);
});
```

The console logs the value correctly, but instead of getting a stream over the entire dragging process, I get the value where it is when its pressed.

How to fix this?

Comment: use change instead `$('#fader').change()`

Comment: Hey Robbie, sorry for asking but i dont really get what you mean. $( "#fader" ).change{}, like so?

Comment: `$('#fader').change()` is the `change()` event being fired.

Comment: @decoye that's okay, no need to apologize. Simply replace mousedown with change. what `.mousedown(function(value))` does is add an event listener that reponds to a mousedown event and calls that function when it registers a mousedown. So `.change(function(value))` does the same thing, but it listens for a change in value instead of a mousedown event. Hope that clears things up!

Comment: hey robbie, exactly the way as i was expecting it, but its not...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this code and I believe you will achieve what you were trying to:

```
$('#fader').change(function(event) {
    console.log(document.querySelector('#intensity').value);
});
```

The *slider* gives you a value when you *slide* it. On *sliding*, it fires the `change` event.

**UPDATE**

You can use the `on('slide')` method to get to know the **value at every point** while you slide it.

```
$('#fader').on('slide', function(event, ui) {
    console.log(ui.value);
});
```

Here is some detail about the `on('slide')` event:

> `slide( event, ui )`
>
> Triggered on every mouse move during slide. The value provided in the event as `ui.value` represents the value that the handle will have as a result of the current movement. Canceling the event will prevent the handle from moving and the handle will continue to have its previous value.

Please do refer to this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilzac95/XUyKs/51/) for more details.

Comment: hey Nikhil, thanks for your answer. thats also what i thought, but its unfortunately not, it only updates on release on the mouse.

Comment: Hey, $('#fader').on('slidechange', function(event) {
    console.log(document.querySelector('#intensity').value);
}); unfortunately does this not even call the function

Comment: i found on stack another user that had the same issue, and this fiddle was suggested, http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/XUyKs/, but the console log behavior is simply the same. maybe its useful to add that im on macosx and chrome browser.

Comment: it tells me that 'slide' is not a function

Comment: I too am using macOSX and working on chrome. Can u plz go through the fiddle that I've added and check if that is what you wanted?

Comment: hey tried it with on('slide'). does not work either.

Comment: hey, cant find your fiddle.

Comment: it works great on your fiddle, but unfortunately not in my code. is there any dependency requirements that i have to include other than jquery-3.2.1.min.js?

Comment: ive included the dependencies now, but still ive got not luck here on my side

Comment: yes, infact exactly the same, but i need to get slider vales parsed

Comment: can i use the ids of the inputs or outputs instead of the div-class?

Comment: will try that now

Comment: with my code in the fiddle it does not work so will now put yours into mine to try to make it work with your exact code

Comment: Here you go buddy, this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilzac95/XUyKs/54/) is with your code. Hope this helps.

Comment: where exeactly do i need to include the jquery-ui.min.js in my index.html?

Comment: buddy, i dont know what and i definately dont know why, but i owe you plenty of beer. thanks a bunch!!!

Comment: oh guys... now that we figured it all out here with the mousemove... i dont dare to ask it, but how to handle it with touch at the same time?